# Mobiledevices: action missing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, http-status-code-400

I am trying to perform a POST of the action, however, when I make the request I get code 400 speaking that the action value is missing.

my code:

```
function mobileAPIPOST() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/devices/mobile/fakexQ_fake0Z0dKFdSblfakeTnnfakel7IYwixfake4ddZfakeAIvnmu/action", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      data: {
        "action": "block"
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    });

}
```

I updated the code following the response from @TheMaster.

My updated code:

```
function mobileAPIPOST() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/devices/mobile/fakexQ_fake0Z0dKFdSblfakeTnnfakel7IYwixfake4ddZfakeAIvnmu/action", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      payload: {
        "action": "block"
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    });

}
```

error pointed out:

```
{
  "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "parseError",
        "message": "Parse Error"
       }
      ],
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Parse Error"
     }
    }
```

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(payload) as shown in the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UrlFetchApp doesn't have a `data` key parameter. Use `payload` instead.

#### Reference:

[UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

#### Code Snippet:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      },
      contentType:  'application/json',
      payload: JSON.stringify({
        "action": "block"
      }),
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    });
```

Comment: @Leticia Edit your  question to show the new code and  "Quote" the error

Comment: I added this to my code, I made the request and it returned the code 204. I made the get again, and the requested change in POST was not made.