# Draftable.com API giving truncated response when passed a JSON in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am trying to call an API from draftable.com (https://api.draftable.com/v1/comparisons) using Google App Script. The API takes two files and returns a string. I have made the GET and DELETE functions which are working fine, but when I run a POST function I am getting an error at the

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL",object);
```

> Error: Request failed for https://api.draftable.com/v1/comparisons
>   returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"left":["This field is
>   required."],"right":["This field is required."]}

I am passing a JSON like the code below:

```
function POST() {

  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Token {iputmytokenhere}",
    },

    "left": {
      "source_url": "https://api.draftable.com/static/test-documents/paper/left.pdf",
      "display_name": "old-example.docx",
      "file_type": "pdf"
    },
    "right": {
      "source_url": "https://api.draftable.com/static/test-documents/paper/right.pdf",
      "display_name": "newer-example.docx",
      "file_type": "pdf"
    }
  };


  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.draftable.com/v1/comparisons", options);
  var params = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());

  Logger.log(params.identifier);
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me why is the error coming.

Comment: Possible an API interaction issue?

Comment: *Equivalent curl code:*

`curl -X POST 
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: Token iputmytokenhere' 
-F left.source_url=https://api.draftable.com/static/test-documents/paper/left.pdf 
-F left.display_name=a1 
-F left.file_type=pdf 
-F right.source_url=https://api.draftable.com/static/test-documents/paper/right.pdf 
-F right.display_name=a2 
-F right.file_type=pdf -F public=false  
'https://api.draftable.com/v1/comparisons'
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobiledevices: action missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416512/mobiledevices-action-missing)