# How to use payload with method get?

Tags: ajax, google-apps-script, jsonp, urlfetch, http-method

I'm trying to learn how to query for data from a local government data site (hoping I can teach my math students to do some data analysis). I'm hoping to get the data and insert them into Google Sheets. The following is a sample provided by the official site on how to do a query:

```
var data = {
  resource_id: '1b702208-44bf-4829-b620-4615ee19b57c', // the resource id
  limit: 5, // get 5 results
  q: 'jones' // query for 'jones'
};
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Total results found: ' + data.result.total)
 }
});$
```

I tried the following code in Google Apps Script:

```
function testapi(){
  var data = {
    resource_id: '1b702208-44bf-4829-b620-4615ee19b57c', // the resource id
    limit: 5, // get 5 results
    q: 'Yishun' 
  };

  var url = "https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,data).getContentText();
}
```

I receive a 404 error. I think the option "data" was not passed.

Would appreciate some help. I am a math teacher, not a coding expert.

Update: I changed the code to this but still 404 error.

```
function testapi(){
  var data = {
    resource_id: '1b702208-44bf-4829-b620-4615ee19b57c', // the resource id
    limit: 5, // get 5 results
    q: 'Yishun' // query for 'jones'
  };

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };  

  var url = "https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search";
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText();

  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobiledevices: action missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416512/mobiledevices-action-missing)

Comment: I changed the code but still got a 404 error.

Comment: The ``method`` is wrong.

Comment: I did change the method to get but the error remains.

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

Whenever `payload` key is present in `options`/`params` argument of `UrlFetchApp`, the `method` is set to `post` by default. And any attempt to change the method to get is "silently" ignored. Other similar scripting platforms automatically convert the `payload` to url query parameters. But, `UrlFetchApp` silently changes the method to post and nothing else.

#### Solution:

Re-create the data object as a query string. For example, `data:{x:1,y:2}` should be changed to `?x=1&y=2` and appended to url.

#### Snippet:

```
function testapi() {
  var options = {
    method: 'get',
    // 'contentType': 'application/json',
    // 'payload' : data,//If set, method is ignored.
    headers: { Accept: '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };

  var url = 'https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search';
  //var url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'; test the method

  function objectToQueryParams(obj) {
    return (
      '?' +
      Object.entries(obj)
        .map(([k, v]) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`)
        .join('&')
    );
  }
  var data = {
    resource_id: '1b702208-44bf-4829-b620-4615ee19b57c', // the resource id
    limit: 5, // get 5 results
    q: 'Yishun', // query for 'Yishun'
  };
  var query = objectToQueryParams(data);
  url += query;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

```js
function objectToQueryParams(obj) {
  return (
    '?' +
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([k, v]) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`)
      .join('&')
  );
}


var data = {
  resource_id: '1b702208-44bf-4829-b620-4615ee19b57c', // the resource id
  limit: 5, // get 5 results
  q: 'Yishun', // query for 'jones'
};
console.log(objectToQueryParams(data));
```

#### Related:

[UrlSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams#Examples)