# Why can't I get my UrlFetchApp.fetch to use the doGet()?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

If I use two forms that are both the same but one has a method of GET and one has a method of POST when I run them one uses the doGet and the other uses the doPost().  But that doesn't happen when I do the same thing with the UrlFetch() command by providing the input from a Prompt.

The html:

The top form is a GET and the bottom form is POST.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h3>GET</h3>
    <form action="https://script.google.com/a/cooper/macros/s/AKfycbzlYgw2cw8q7u9qTxM/exec" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="one" value="" />
      <br /><input type="text" name="two" value="" />
      <br /><textarea rows="2" cols="25" name="three" placeholder="Enter Text Here"></textarea>
      <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
 <h3>POST</h3>   
    <form action="https://script.google.com/a/cooper/macros/s/AKfycbzlYgw2cw8q7u9qTxM/exec" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="one" value="" />
      <br /><input type="text" name="two" value="" />
      <br /><textarea rows="2" cols="25" name="three" placeholder="Enter Text Here"></textarea>
      <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs:

```
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log('doGet: %s',JSON.stringify(e));
  if(e.parameter) {
    var data=e.parameter;
    handleFunction(data,'get');//This hardwires the term get to the ouput
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('testing');
}

function doPost(e){
  console.log('doPost Entry',JSON.stringify(e));
  if(e.postData.length!=-1) {
    var data=e.parameter;
    handleFunction(data,'post');//This hardwires the term post to the ouput
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('doPost Return:' + JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents));
}

function handleFunction(data,source){
  console.log('handleFunction Entry: %s',JSON.stringify(data));
  var one=data.one;
  var two=data.two;
  var three=data.three;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([source,one,two,three]);
}

function postit() {
  // DriveApp.getFiles() //I copied this from a Tanaike example.  I don't know if I need it still
  var ask=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter first/second/third/method", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK) 
  if(ask.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    var dA=ask.getResponseText().split('/');//Just an easy way to get 4 pieces of data at one time
    if(dA.length==4) {
      var url=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
      var data={"one":dA[0],"two":dA[1],"three":dA[2]};
      //the method is provide from the last term of the above prompt
      var options={"method":dA[3],"payload":data,"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},"muteHttpExceptions": true};
      var resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      Logger.log('UrlFetch Response: %s',resp);
    }
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]

**This what I ended up with and it runs in Rhino and V8**

```
function postit() {
  // DriveApp.getFiles() 
  var ask = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter first/second/third/method", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  if (ask.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    var dA = ask.getResponseText().split('/');
    if (dA.length == 4) {
      if (dA[3] == "POST") {
        var url = getDeploymentUrl();
        var data = { "one": dA[0], "two": dA[1], "three": dA[2] };
        var options = { "method": dA[3], "payload": data, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, "muteHttpExceptions": true };
      } else if (dA[3] == "GET") {
        var url = Utilities.formatString('%s?one=%s&two=%s&three=%s', getDeploymentUrl(), dA[0], dA[1], dA[2]);
        var data = { "one": dA[0], "two": dA[1], "three": dA[2] };
        var options = { "method": dA[3], "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, "muteHttpExceptions": true };
      }
      Logger.log('url: %s \n options: %s', url, options);
      var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    }
  }
}

function getDeploymentUrl() {
  const scriptId = gobj.globals.scriptid;
  const base = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"
  const url1 = base + scriptId + "/deployments";
  const options = { "method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options);
  const robj = JSON.parse(r);
  const deploymentId = robj.deployments[robj.deployments.length - 1].deploymentId;
  const deploymenturl = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/xxx/s/" + deploymentId + "/exec";
  return deploymenturl;
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56216818/ (Not as good as Tanaike's answer, but just linking it to this question)

Comment: Thanks that's useful for a more universal solution with an unknown payload. To be honest this is that first time I really got into the guts of UrlFetch.  I've been looking at other peoples questions for a while and was picking up a few things here and there but there's nothing doing it yourself to figure what you don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

I think that the reason of your issue is due to the data is requested with `payload` for `POST` and `GET` methods. At UrlFetchApp, it seems that when the data is used as `payload`, POST method is used, even when `method` is `GET`. In order to send the data as GET method, please add them to the query parameter.

(I thought that when the data is send as `payload` with the GET method, the data could be sent as `GET` before. But about this, I only had a faint memory. I apologize for this.)

In order to avoid this, how about the following modification as the simple modification?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the query parameter is used for the GET method.

#### Modified script:

```
function postit() {
  // DriveApp.getFiles() //I copied this from a Tanaike example.  I don't know if I need it still
  var ask=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter first/second/third/method", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK) 
  if(ask.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    var dA=ask.getResponseText().split('/');//Just an easy way to get 4 pieces of data at one time
    if(dA.length==4) {
      var url=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

      // --- I modified below script.
      var potions = {};
      if (dA[3] == "POST") {
        var data={"one":dA[0],"two":dA[1],"three":dA[2]};
        //the method is provide from the last term of the above prompt
        options={"method":dA[3],"payload":data,"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},"muteHttpExceptions": true};
      } else if (dA[3] == "GET") {
        options={"method":dA[3],"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},"muteHttpExceptions": true};
        url += `?one=${dA[0]}&two=${dA[1]}&three=${dA[2]}`;
      }
      // ---

      var resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      Logger.log('UrlFetch Response: %s',resp);
    }
  }
}
```

### Note:

- Please enable V8.
- `// DriveApp.getFiles()` of the comment line is used for automatically adding the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` with the script editor. This is used for accessing to Web Apps using the access token.

### References:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

If I misunderstood your issue and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I couldn't get the `"x-http-method-override"` to work in either RHINO or V8 and the first version of course runs in V8 but not in Rhino due the string literal I think.

Comment: I used the first version with Utilities.formatString() instead of string literal.

Comment: @Cooper I have to apologize that the pattern 2 couldn't be used for this situation. When I tested it one more again, I could also confirm it. In this case, the GET method is converted to POST method. So `doPost` was run. This was my mistake. I deeply apologize for this. So I deleted the pattern 2.

Comment: You have nothing to apologize for I have benefited immensely from our association on this forum. Thank you.

Comment: Adding some more info if it helps others as I had to do some research to refresh my memory. With the HTML/web standard, `GET` request use URL paramaters which is why you have to add the submission values to the URL -- like in the example above. Also, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app also mentions GET does not accept `payload`.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. `x-http-method-override` is used for converting the method. So in this case, the GET method is converted to the POST method. By this, `doPost` is run when the GET method is requested. I had forgotten about this. About converting the JSON object to the query parameter, also this sample script might be able to be used. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/70503e0ea6998083fcb05c6d2a857107