# GET request with a body, Google Script App

Tags: google-apps-script, http-get, urlfetch, rest

I would like to make a GET request with Google Script App on a RestAPI. I was planning on using the function fetchAPI(url, params). Here is the list of arguments I can use in parameters:
[params arguments from   https://developers.google.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2e9J.png)

I don't see "body" in the list of arguments. Does that mean it's not possible to make a GET request WITH BODY with the Google script App?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Not only in apps script, but in all cases.

Comment: @TheMaster are you sure? we can use in all cases except google apps script.

Comment: @dgknca  [Checking again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body), it does seem possible but not http compliant at least in server side to do anything with the body.

Comment: @dgknca Having said that, I believe most libraries convert the body to url query parameters. You're probably looking for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200001/jsonp-ajax-in-google-script/56216818

Comment: @TheMaster unfortunately it doesn't work in my case. I click 'connect' and nothing happens. I guess we need to convert the API working logic to POST.

Comment: @dgknca What do you mean by "connect"?

Comment: @TheMaster sorry. I'm trying to bind a data to google data studio.

Comment: @dgknca I guess It's better to ask a new question(where data studio experts might also help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official documentation [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

GET requests do not accept a payload body.

> "the payload (that is, the POST body) for the request. Certain HTTP
> methods (for example, GET) do not accept a payload."

Answer (score 0):

An example of using UrlFetchApp:
In this example, you can GET the JSON content.

```
function CallAPI() {
  
  // 
  
  var token = ""; // Example key
  
  // Call the API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.something");
  
  // Analyze JSON
  var content = response.getContentText();
  
  Logger.log(content);
  
  var obj = JSON.parse(content, function (key, value) {
  if (key == "status") {
    Logger.log("value status is = " + value);
  } else if (key == "origin")
  {
   Logger.log("The value origin is= " + value);
  }
}); 
  
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question