# Sending parameters with UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I was trying to make a GET request, but according to the documentation of the API it requires extra parameters to makes me access the data. I searched for how to send `params` using `UrlFetch` and i found the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) which is talking mainly about sending parameters in `POST` not `GET` request.

I already send `Headers` in the `UrlFetch` request for **Authentication**, but i want to send extra parameters.

So is there's an easy way to do this?

Below is an example of what I'm doing and what i want to do.

**My code:**

```
   const someService = authorize();
  
   let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.webSite.com/api/teams.json', {
    headers: {
      // Sending access token in the request
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + someService.getAccessToken()
    }
  });
```

**What I want to do**

```
   const someService = authorize();
  
   let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.webSite.com/api/teams.json', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + someService.getAccessToken()
    },
    parameters:{
         'teamId': 1234
     }
      });
// URL should be like that: https://www.webSite.com/api/teams.json?access_token=1234abc&teamId=1234
```

Comment: Either you should use `POST` or `GET` depends on either you want to retrieve data from the website or upload data to the website. The correct way to authenticate heavily depends on the specific API. Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis). Use `muteHttpExceptions: true` to explore the errors you get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56216818/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UrlFetchApp class unfortunately does not have a built-in method to automatically generate the URL search parameters from an object. But Google provides one in their [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/ade8b9a8c5e8117ea18bcd14fcd1bb779a3425f8/src/Utilities.js#L20) that you can copy:

```
function sendRequest() {
  const someService = authorize();
  let baseUrl = 'https://www.webSite.com/api/teams.json';
  let params = {
    'access_token': someService.getAccessToken(),
    'teamId': 1234
  };
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(buildUrl_(baseUrl, params));
}

/**
 * Builds a complete URL from a base URL and a map of URL parameters.
 * @param {string} url The base URL.
 * @param {Object.<string, string>} params The URL parameters and values.
 * @return {string} The complete URL.
 * @private
 */
function buildUrl_(url, params) {
  var paramString = Object.keys(params).map(function(key) {
    return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
  }).join('&');
  return url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + paramString;
}
```