How to pass parameters in the body of a GET api call with UrlFetchApp
​Hi,
I’m desperately trying to call this API with Google Apps Script:  Get issue limit report.
The documentation says to pass this parameter as payload this object: { "issuesApproachingLimitParams": { "worklog": 8000 }.
Unfortunately it seems that the UrlFetchApp class does not allow you to specify the payload in GET calls.
Anyway, I tried as follows and, obviously, it doesn't work:
var url = "https://my-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/limit/report?isReturningKeys=true";

var params = { "issuesApproachingLimitParams": {"worklog": 8000} };

var options = { 
  method: "get",  
  muteHttpExceptions: true,  

  payload : JSON.stringify(params), // not recognized !!

  headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + MY-TOKEN,
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

var req = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

This is because I'm trying to turn this CURL into a Google Apps Script function which instead works:

curl --request GET \
 --url 'https://my-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/limit/report?isReturningKeys=true' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic <MY-TOKEN>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{ "issuesApproachingLimitParams": { "worklog": 8000 } }'

Is there anyone who can help me?
Thanks a lot in advance
Mike

Can you try removing the JSON.stringify ? Write the payload like this payload : params,

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/ Also try https://httpbin.org/ with curl and Urlfetchapp/GET.

If I remove JSON.stringify I get http error 405

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56216818/
